# Is this a cascading list? And what would be an alternate or better pattern to use?

Tags: tables, lists

[image]

I am referring to the list of documents and then clicking on one and editing/viewing it on the right. Is there a better way to do this? This list probably won't be as long as it is in my example.

I don't think a modal would be appropriate for editing a list or drilling down like iOS.

Comment: Could you provide more information for what you are asking? Posting the question only in the subject line is also not advised. What type of cascading list are you talking about? Of what part of the screen shot are you referring to? Please elaborate on your question, this will help provide you with better answers.

Comment: Sorry, first timer! I am referring to the list of documents and then clicking on one and editing/viewing it on the right.

Is there a better way to do this? This list probably won't be as long as it is in my example.

Comment: Not a problem! That's why I left the comment, to help you along and get you better answers.

Comment: Thanks man! I can't think of another option for handling this.

Comment: Some additional questions. What is the target screen size? Is this desktop with mobile potential? You mentioned that the list of documents probably won't be as long as you have it, but is there potential for a large list (keep edge cases in mind)? What is the audience, are administrators using this, or a broad public? And lastly, what is the context of this action? What is the user trying to accomplish here? Sorry for all the questions on clarification! Just trying to understand what a user would be thinking.

Comment: Great questions that I also asked when gathering requirements.

1.) Desktop only
2.) Administrative
3.) The user is an admin for a community. They need to be able to provide documents for all the users to fill out in order to be a compliant member of the community.

For instance, if the user needs to fill out a 1099 tax form, the admin can create a place for it in the system, name it, make it either required or optional and possibly provide a template, or pdf of the document for users to download.

Comment: As a side comment - if the 'edit' button enables form editing, there really shouldn't be a save button - the edit button should change to save once pressed. Can you save without pressing edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered from the comments, let me make an assumptions to the application:
*-The list of documents will not be modified frequently. Besides initial configuration, an administrator will not be using/modifying the list frequently.*

Also, this answer is based off of the layout of the page/actions (as that is what I believe you are asking), not the design of buttons, or location of buttons.

**To answer your initial question on whether or not it's a cascading list, it is not (but has potential to depending on how you plan on navigating).**
Let's first state that we want the user to be able to *accomplish their tasks with the least amount of clicks, and the most amount of comprehension and intuitive actions*.
Now, a use case. Suppose the user navigates to this application and hits the Documents panel. Chances are, they are there to modify the All Documents tab (that can change depending on how you feel the users are using the application), so they will not have to click *again* on one of those tabs, it opens one automatically. So the user clicks Documents, and the All Documents tab is automatically selected, and the list of documents is already shown. At this point, modifying a document is only one more click (selecting the document to edit). Listing our action steps, we have:
1. Select Documents
2. Select Document to edit

These kinds of clicking actions make sense, and are intuitive. I want to modify a Document, so I click the Documents navigation (on the left), and then select the desired document.

I agree that a modal dialog for accomplishing this would be a bit much and cumbersome. With this UI, the user can easily navigate to the desired document to modify, but then quickly return to Home, or Products.

Additionally, this design has a good separation of functionality. There is a clear line between navigation, actions, and configuration, with having the "3-Panel" layout. And I know you said you weren't looking mobile, but it is good to note that a design like this allows for easy mobile design in the future (by ultimately making it a drill down, or a compressed drill down).

**To answer your other question, is there a better option?**
I might make the argument that there is *always* a better option, but those options typically only present themselves with time. A design that was great 10 years ago may not be great today. Based off what I'm seeing/hearing, this design would accomplish your tasks. So the question arises, have there been any negative comments to this design that you have received?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for putting all of my concerns and thoughts down so eloquently. You were also 100% correct in your assumptions.

I have not received any negative feedback.

The owner of our company wants it to be AWESOME and while I find any UI work that may seem mundane for most people to be AWESOME, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some other pattern that would be MORE AWESOME!

Thanks!

Comment: Does it help/answer the question? Can I clarify anything mentioned?

Comment: Yes, it does. Working alone in UX and UI is hard sometimes. I am glad I found this community.

Comment: Oh, and what is this pattern called?

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it sufficiently answered your question, you can mark that post as the answer. Additionally, you can vote up an answer to help it be more visible to others trying to find the answer to a similar question. Can't tell you how many times it's helped me as well. Stack Exchange has many other sites to get help too, you can browse a quick list at the bottom of the page. In regards to what this pattern is officially called, I do not have a name to place with it, unfortunately.

Comment: A vote up on the post that answers is always appreciated as well :)

Comment: I don't have enough rep points to vote up :(
Sorry.

Comment: Gotcha gotcha. I thought that the person who posted could always vote up, my mistake!